# html background-image doesnt show up on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, background-image, screen

I have a perfectly working hosted website...on theory. I did all the responsiveness and I was testing it on a computer with mobile browser emulators. It is working with minor mistakes (which I am aware, and will fix). But here is the biggest challenge. If I run my website in emulator on the computer it does everything nicely. But from phone, it doesnt load the background-image.

[image]

So I excluded that problem would be with being responsive, problem must lay somewhere in mobile phones (both times ran by Chrome). Also doesnt work properly on other mobiles too.
Any idea or suggestion towards the mystery?
Thanks,
Koppany

Comment: I dont have... + we tried from different phones in different sizes with the same result.

Comment: If you can make a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, that would be nice. Otherwise, you may have to give us a link to the website. Without it, there's not much we can do.

Comment: www.nofailz.com

Comment: Btw.. my background picture is 3648*5472. Could it be good for PC but too big for a mobile browser?

Comment: Speaking of your domain name, you should check console and research until you're able to remove the red lines. As of now you're quite far from having a *"perfectly working hosted website"*.

Comment: Indeed its true, thats why I said it is working with minor mistakes. However I dont think those red lines would generate my problem. If yes, it shouldnt be working from computer too.